# How to call a silverlight application from another silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How do I call a silverlight application from another silverlight application. I want to do it when User RMB click on the menu item on the treeview from first application.
Please note these menu items are added dynamically hence I can not add the code in the XAML file.
Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how two separate running Silverlight applications can communicate with each other?  If so you can use the Messaging API.  You simply need to set up a receiver and sender.  http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/10/07/silverlight-3-local-messaging-explained-enhancement